# Webpack Angular2 don’t receive response (an object) from http Post

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am trying to validate user login using http Post using webpack.  I am able to pass the user information and validated the user again db table.  The server codes work fine. However, I stumble in the passing the response (an object) from the server back to the client. The similar codes work in DotNet Core with Angular2 SPA (codes extracted and modified from chsakell Cross-platform SPA with ASP.NET core 1.0, Angular 2 & TypeScript).  But it fails in the DotNet Core with Angular2 in webpack. I hope someone could help to help to identify where the problems are.

```
System.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;
using UCHICUDRS.Formatters;
using System.Security.Claims;
using UCHICUDRS.Models;
using UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Repositories;
using UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Mappings;

namespace UCHICUDRS
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static string _applicationPath = string.Empty;
        private static string _contentRootPath = string.Empty;

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            _applicationPath = env.WebRootPath;
            _contentRootPath = env.ContentRootPath;

            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<UCHICUDRSContext>(options =>
               options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:UCHICUDRSConnection:ConnectionString"]));

            // Repositories                services.AddScoped<ILogRepository, LogRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IRoleRepository, RoleRepository>();                services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRequestRepository, UserRequestRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserGroupRepository, UserGroupRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserRoleRepository, UserRoleRepository>();

            // Services
            services.AddScoped<IMembershipService, MembershipService>();
            services.AddScoped<IEncryptionService, EncryptionService>();

            services.AddAuthentication();

            // Polices
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                // inline policies
                options.AddPolicy("Administrator", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("Manager", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Manager");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User");
                });

                options.AddPolicy("No Access", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, " No Access");
                });
            });
/*
            // Add MVC services to the services container
            // Causing http header error
            services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                var resolver = opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
                if (resolver != null)
                {
                    var res = resolver as DefaultContractResolver;
                    res.NamingStrategy = null;
                }
            });
*/
            // Add framework services. 
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                // The custom formatters need to be added to the MVC middleware, so that it knows how to handle media types 'text/csv'. 
                options.InputFormatters.Add(new CsvInputFormatter());
                options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter());
                options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("csv", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}


operationResult.ts

export class OperationResult {
    Succeeded: boolean;
    Message: string;
    RetData: any;
 
    constructor(succeeded: boolean, message: string, retData: any) {
        this.Succeeded = succeeded;
        this.Message = message;
        this.RetData = retData;
    }
}


    login.component.ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';    // for showModelMsg
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';
    // import {FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';
    import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

    import { Login } from '../../../core/models/login';
    import { User } from '../../../core/models/user';
    import { Role } from '../../../core/models/role';
    import { OperationResult } from '../../../core/models/operationResult';
    import { MembershipService } from '../../../core/services/membership.service';
     
    @Component({
        selector: 'login',
        providers: [MembershipService, NotificationService],
        template: require('./login.component.html'),
        styles: [require('./account.component.css')]
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
        private _user: Login = new Login('', '', false);

        private notificationService: NotificationService;  // alertify is no longer be supported so when it put inside the constructor, the html won't display
        // private router: Router;
        private route: ActivatedRoute;

        constructor(private membershipService: MembershipService, private router: Router) { }

        ngOnInit() {
            this._user.Username = '';
            this._user.Password = '';
            this._user.RememberMe = false;
        }

        login(): void {
            var _authenticationResult: OperationResult = new OperationResult(false, '', null);
            var _creds: User;
            this.membershipService.login(this._user)
                .subscribe(res => {  
                    _authenticationResult.Succeeded = res.Succeeded;
                    _authenticationResult.Message = res.Message;
                    _authenticationResult.RetData = res.RetData;
                    _creds = _authenticationResult.RetData;
                },
                error => console.error('Error: ' + error),  // error from http call
                () => {  
                    if (_authenticationResult.Succeeded) {
                        this.notificationService.printSuccessMessage('Welcome back ' + this._user.Username + '!');
                        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(_creds));
                        this.router.navigate(['home']);
                    }
                    else {
                        this.showModelMsg("Login Failed", _authenticationResult.Message);
                    }
                });
        };
    }


    membership.service.ts
    import { Http, Response, Request } from '@angular/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { DataService } from './data.service';
    import { Login } from '../models/login';
    import { Registration } from '../models/registration';
    import { Role } from '../models/role';
    import { User } from '../models/user';
    import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
     
    @Injectable()
    export class MembershipService {
        private _accountLoginAPI: string = 'api/account/authenticate/';
        private _res: Observable<any>;
        public redirectUrl: string;   // store the URL so we can redirect after loggin in

        constructor(public accountService: DataService) { }
     
     
        login(creds: Login) {
            this.accountService.set(this._accountLoginAPI);
            return this.accountService.post(JSON.stringify(creds));
        }
    }


    data.service.ts
    import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
    import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    // import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
    import { OperationResult } from '../models/operationResult';
     
    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {
     
        public _pageSize: number;
        public _baseUri: string;
        public _headers: Headers;
        public _options: RequestOptions;
     
        constructor(public http: Http) {
            this.init();
        }

        init() {
            this._headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' });
            this._options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this._headers });
        }
     
        post(data?: any, mapJson: boolean = true) {
            var _authenticationResult: OperationResult = new OperationResult(false, '', null);
            if (mapJson)  {
                var res = this.http.post(this._baseUri, data, this._options)
                                    .map(response => <any>(<Response>response).json());
                return res;
            }
            else
                return this.http.post(this._baseUri, data, this._options)
                    .map(response => response.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
        }
    }


AccountController.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using UCHICUDRS.Models;
using UCHICUDRS.ViewModels;
using UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Repositories;
using UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Services;
using UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Core;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using AutoMapper;


namespace UCHICUDRS.Controllers
{   // https://chsakell.com/2016/01/01/cross-platform-single-page-applications-with-asp-net-5-angular-2-typescript/
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IMembershipService _membershipService;
        private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
        private readonly IRoleRepository _roleRepository;
        private readonly ILogRepository _loggingRepository;

        public AccountController(IMembershipService membershipService,
            IUserRepository userRepository,
            IRoleRepository roleRepository,
            ILogRepository _errorRepository)
        {
            _membershipService = membershipService;
            _userRepository = userRepository;
            _roleRepository = roleRepository;
            _loggingRepository = _errorRepository;
        }

        [HttpPost("authenticate")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] Login user)
        {
            IActionResult _result = new ObjectResult(false);
            GenericResult _authenticationResult = null;
            Console.WriteLine("123");
            try
            {
                MembershipContext _userContext = _membershipService.ValidateUser(user.Username, user.Password);

                if (_userContext.User != null)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Role> _roles = _userRepository.GetRoles(user.Username);
                    List<Claim> _claims = new List<Claim>();
                    foreach (Role role in _roles)
                    {
                        Claim _claim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role.Name, ClaimValueTypes.String, user.Username);
                        _claims.Add(_claim);
                    }
                    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(_claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)),
                        new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = user.RememberMe });

                    _authenticationResult = new GenericResult()
                    {
                        Succeeded = true,
                        Message = "Authentication succeeded",
                        RetData = _userContext.User
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    _authenticationResult = new GenericResult()
                    {
                        Succeeded = false,
                        Message = "Username and Password don't match. Authentication failed.",
                        RetData = null
                    };
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _authenticationResult = new GenericResult()
                {
                    Succeeded = false,
                    Message = ex.Message,
                    RetData = null
                };

                _loggingRepository.Add(new Log() { Message = ex.Message, StackTrace = ex.StackTrace, RecIn = DateTime.Now });
                _loggingRepository.Commit();
            }

            _result = new ObjectResult(_authenticationResult);
            return _result;
        }
}


GenericResult.cs
namespace UCHICUDRS.Infrastructure.Core
{
    public class GenericResult
    {
        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public object RetData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the following codes in the system.cs

```
        system.cs
            services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(opt =>
        {
            var resolver = opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver;
            if (resolver != null)
            {
                var res = resolver as DefaultContractResolver;
                res.NamingStrategy = null;
            }
        });
```

I commented it because it caused the http call failed.  Then I manually add http header to the http to make it work.  Not when I uncomment the above codes, the http post response transit data back to the client. Even though the codes work now but I don't know the reason.